# SFML - particle system vector out of range

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

I am using SFML to design a particle system. The problem is that the game gets slow and moreover I keep on getting `vector subscript out of range`.

Here is my code:

```
    #pragma once
#include<SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include"stdafx.h"

struct particle
{
    sf::Vector2<float> pos;
    sf::Vector2<float> vel;
    sf::Color color;
};

class pengine

{
private:
    std::list<particle*> hitspark;
    std::list<particle*>::iterator it;
    int size;
    sf::Image img;
    sf::Texture text;
    sf::Sprite sp;
public:
    pengine();
    void fuel(sf::Vector2f);
    void update();
    void render(sf::RenderWindow &name);
    void cleanup();
};
pengine::pengine()
{
    img.create(with,heit,sf::Color::Transparent);
    hitspark.clear();
    text.create(with,heit);
    sp.setTexture(text);
}
void pengine::fuel(sf::Vector2f v1)
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        particle* p;
        p->color=sf::Color(rand()%255,rand()%255,rand()%255);
        p->pos=v1;
        float r1 = (float)rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/6.238);
        float r2 = (float)rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/6.238);
        p->vel.x=cos(r1);
        p->vel.y=cos(r2);
        if(p->vel.x!=0.0f&&p->vel.y!=0.0f)
        {
            hitspark.push_back(p);
            delete p;
            continue;
        }
        else {
        delete p;
        continue;}
    }
}
void pengine::update()
{
    for(it=hitspark.begin();it!=hitspark.end();it++)
    {
        (*it)->pos.x+=(*it)->vel.x;
        (*it)->pos.y+=(*it)->vel.y;
        (*it)->vel.x-=0.005;
        (*it)->vel.y-=0.005;
    }
    cleanup();
}
void pengine::cleanup()
{
    for(std::list<particle*>::iterator t=hitspark.begin();t!=hitspark.end();t++)
    {
        if((*t)->vel.x==0.0f && (*t)->vel.y==0.0f)                            
         {
             std::list<particle*>::iterator it=hitspark.end() ;
             it--;
             std::swap(*t,*it);
             delete (*it);
             hitspark.pop_back();
         }
        if((*t)->pos.x<=0||(*t)->pos.x>=with||(*t)->pos.y<=0||(*t)->pos.y>=heit)
        {
            std::list<particle*>::iterator it=hitspark.end() ;
             it--;
             std::swap(*t,*it);
             delete (*it);
             hitspark.pop_back();
        }

    }
}
void pengine::render(sf::RenderWindow &name)
{
    for(std::list<particle*>::iterator s=hitspark.begin();s!=hitspark.end();s++)
    {
        img.setPixel((int)((*s)->pos.x),(int)((*s)->pos.y),(*s)->color);
    }
    const sf::Uint8*piarray=img.getPixelsPtr();
    text.update(piarray);
    name.draw(sp);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
particle* p;
```

Should be

```
particle* p = new particle();
```

Another tip would be to

```
typedef std::list<particle*> Particles;
```

so you can go Particles::iterator. A bit cleaner.

Lastly I'd like to say that you're doing things all wrong. Particle systems should have constant size with probably an array or an std::vector if you're lazy. Not a linked list with pointers in it.

so either

```
std::vector<particle>
```

or

```
template<int MAX_PARTICLES>
class ParticleSystem
{ Particle particles[MAX_PARTICLES]; };
```

I hope you get the idea, it's much much faster without the cache misses. I prefer the latter, but may just be me.